# Upload info to a server so one can not get the files back before a certain time

Tags: web

do you know any webservice or kind of a system where I can send a file and the system returns it to me after a preset time (for instance one day or one week, etc). Also that one can not get it before by any means.

One application would be to blindly change my facebook password, copy it, and mail or upload to this system. It gets returned in two days, and during these two days, i do not know the password and can not waste time with FB.

Or do you know to some similar approachces?

Thanks

And yes ... I know the ideal solution would be not to procrastinate :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this via snail-mail... Print the item and put it in an envelope without looking at it. Then mail it to yourself.

Or mail a USB stick for files.